# How to paginate results from Elasticsearch DSL in Python

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using [Elasticsearch DSL](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py) and I would like to paginate through the results. To do that, I need to know the total number of results in the search. How should I best do that?

Do I do one search, then execute twice, one generally for the `.hits.total` and the other sliced for items? Something like this:

```
response = Link.search().filter("term", run_id=run_id)
total = response.execute().hits.total
links = response[start:end].execute()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
dsl = Link.search().filter("term", run_id=run_id)
response = dsl[start:end].execute()
links = response.hits.hits
total = response.hits.total
```

... only hits ElasticSearch once.

official docs: https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination